# Solve $\frac{1}{x} = S x$, an equation that includes an element-wise inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, systems-of-equations, matrix-calculus

> Solve the following equation for $x \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$
>
> $$\frac{1}{x} = S x$$
>
> where the inverse on $x$ is taken *element-wise*, and $S \in \mathbb{R}_+^{n\times n}$ is PSD (or PD, if needed).

This problem comes from trying to optimize

$$L(x) = 1_n^T \log(x) - \frac{1}{2} x^T S x$$

where the logarithm is taken element-wise over $x$, and $1_n$ is just a column-vector of $n$ ones. In other words, we're doing `sum(log(x))`.

If it helps (otherwise, ignore it), you can assume that $x$ must sum to a constant.

Because this equation is, at worst, quadratic, I was hoping there would be a closed form solution, or at least a very efficient way of computing the solution short of gradient descent.

Comment: Is $\log x$ defined element-wise for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yup! I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: When you say $x$ is a vector and $\log x$ is element-wise, does that mean that $\log x$ is the vector $(\log x_1, \log x_2, ...)$? If so, isn't your expression $L(x)$ adding a vector to a scalar?

Comment: @JohnBarber so sorry, you're right. A sum is taken after the element-wise log. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: So you're solving for the vector $x$ given some *fixed* matrix $S$, is that right?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not making that clearer. I'll specify in the problem that we're solving for $x$.

Comment: So, let's see. If $S_i$ is the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ row of $S$, then I believe this reduces to the $n$ quadratic equations $S_i \cdot x = 1 / x_i$.

Comment: Based on the form of your $L(x)$, I think you can assume without loss of generality that $S$ is symmetric.

Comment: $S$ being PSD (or PD) automatically implies that it's symmetric. Also, as per StackExchange guidelines, extended discussions like this shouldn't be in the comments, but [continued in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93537/discussion-between-chausies-and-john-barber).

Comment: The Hessian is easy to evaluate. if the problem dimension is not too high, consoder using a trust region Newton method on L(x). That is a convex optimization problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have the following system of equations in $\mathrm x > 0_n$

$$\left( \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \right)^{-1} 1_n = \mathrm S \,\mathrm x$$

Left-multiplying both sides by diagonal matrix $\mbox{diag} (\mathrm x)$,

$$1_n = \mbox{diag} (\mathrm x) \,\mathrm S \,\mathrm x$$

where the $i$-th (quadratic) equation is

$$1 = x_i \sum_{j=1}^n s_{ij} x_j = \mathrm x^\top \mathrm e_i \mathrm s_i^\top \mathrm x = \mbox{tr} \left( \,\mathrm e_i \mathrm s_i^\top \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top \right) = \langle \mathrm s_i \mathrm e_i^\top , \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top \rangle$$

where $\mathrm s_i$ is the $i$-th row (or column) of symmetric matrix $\rm S$.

Let $\mathrm X := \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top$. Hence, we have $n$ linear equality constraints in $\rm X$, a constraint on the rank of $\rm X$ and a positive semidefiniteness constraint

$$\begin{aligned} \langle \mathrm s_1 \mathrm e_1^\top, \mathrm X \rangle &= 1\\ \langle \mathrm s_2 \mathrm e_2^\top, \mathrm X\rangle &= 1\\ &\vdots\\ \langle \mathrm s_n \mathrm e_n^\top, \mathrm X\rangle &= 1\\ \mbox{rank} (\mathrm X) &= 1\\ \mathrm X &\succeq \mathrm O_n\end{aligned}$$

Since the **nuclear norm** is a convex proxy for the rank, we solve the following convex program in $\rm X$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm X \|_*\\ \text{subject to} & \langle \mathrm s_1 \mathrm e_1^\top, \mathrm X \rangle = 1\\ & \langle \mathrm s_2 \mathrm e_2^\top, \mathrm X \rangle = 1\\ & \qquad\vdots\\ & \langle \mathrm s_n \mathrm e_n^\top, \mathrm X \rangle = 1\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

Since matrix $\rm X$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, its eigenvalues are equal to its singular values and, thus, the nuclear norm of matrix $\rm X$ is equal to its trace. Hence, we solve the following (convex) **semidefinite program** (SDP) in $\rm X$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm X \right)\\ \text{subject to} & \langle \mathrm s_1 \mathrm e_1^\top, \mathrm X \rangle = 1\\ & \langle \mathrm s_2 \mathrm e_2^\top, \mathrm X \rangle = 1\\ & \qquad\vdots\\ & \langle \mathrm s_n \mathrm e_n^\top, \mathrm X \rangle = 1\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

Lastly, there are two possibilities:

- If the optimal solution is rank-$1$, then we have solved the system of $n$ quadratic equations.
- If the optimal solution is *not* rank-$1$, then do try another approach. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! But SDP seems like it might just as well bloat the run-time egregiously. It would be nice if the sparsity/structure could be leveraged to get speedups beyond a vanilla SDP solver. In any case, I'll run experiments comparing the run-times of gradient descent, newton's method, and SDP, and add another comment with the results of how their speeds compare.